# MIPS - free dynamically allocated space (heap)

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am trying to free dynamically allocated heap memory space

I've tried running this simple code but I keep getting the same error:

"request (-40) is negative heap amount (syscall 9)"

```
.text
li $v0,9
li $a0,40
syscall

li $v0,9
li $a0,-40
syscall
```

Can anyone help me understand why it is not working?
Is there a different way to free space?

Comment: [How to free the heap memory in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70559682) suggests an algorithm for a simple memory-management function wrapping the sbrk system call.

Answer (score 4):

MARS doesn't support `sbrk` with negative arguments, as you can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/thomasrussellmurphy/MARS_Assembler/blob/master/mars/mips/hardware/Memory.java#L297).

So as far as I can tell there's no way to explicitly free dynamically allocated memory when running your code in MARS.

Answer (score 1):

If you free heap memory by using a negative `sbrk` that basically turns the heap into a stack, as only memory at the end can be returned — that is not really what the heap is about.  In the heap we want to be able to free any arbitrary object, not solely the end.

So, the questions are:

- Why do you need to release heap memory?
- Are you really ok using the heap like a stack?

---

You can implement `malloc` & `free`.  Though these are usually quite complicated due to their general purpose nature and performance considerations, a simple, slow one is pretty easy to write — especially if you have knowledge of your application and its limited requirements.

A truly general purpose `malloc`/`free` uses a data structure that collects the free blocks.  `malloc` first searches that to satisfy a request, hands out an existing free block or else uses sbrk.  `free` returns a block to the collection.  (There's more to it of course: splitting large blocks, merging free blocks...)

However, if you were ok using the heap like a stack, you could maintain two pointers, one indicating where free memory starts, and another where it ends.  Releasing memory most recently allocated (like `sbrk(-400)`) would decrement the free memory start pointer by 400.  Allocating memory would increment free memory start by the desired amount, while also moving the free memory end pointer if needed (using a `sbrk` of whatever size is still needed).

Comment: That *is* how the heap works in real OSes.  Real `malloc` implementations (like in glibc) *do* use sbrk for small allocations (`mmap` for large allocations so memory can be handed back to the OS immediately on free).  And indeed, one unfreed allocation can stop a whole bunch of small allocations from being handed back to the OS with `sbrk`.  But a proper malloc implementation manages its own free list so an application can always free anything it allocated, it's just a question of whether it can be given back *to the OS*.  But from an OS POV, moving the break fwd/back is what sbrk is about.

Comment: So I guess the disconnect is that MARS provides some toy system calls that do things a standard library would normally do, but doesn't provide a malloc implementation, only sbrk.  You're right that from an application POV, that's not what you want from a heap allocator.  I think it's just terminology issue that bothering me about the phrasing in this answer; "the heap" is not a very specific term; I guess you're using it to mean dynamic allocation in general, but not talking about the possibility of implementing `malloc` *on top of* `sbrk`, instead assuming a thin wrapper.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I take your point about "the heap" being unspecific as to whether from the OS point of view or application point of view.  Still, I did mention using sbrk in malloc, i.e. malloc as a layer on top of sbrk.  Not sure I understand the distinction you're going for of on top vs. thin wrapper.

Comment: By "thin wrapper", I meant that `malloc(20)` = `sbrk(+20)`, and free needs to know the size.  "On top" I meant with a user-space free list, like a real malloc implementation, using `sbrk` behind the scenes to get more core when the free list is empty.  (And returning some to the OS when possible, if the free list is larger than some threshold and there's a contiguous free chunk at the high end of the break.  As you say, a never-freed allocation does stop a malloc implementation from unmapping anything earlier.)