# How to free the heap memory in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator, sbrk

For learning purposes, I'm trying to implement a stack in the heap memory.

When I push something I just need to do the systemcall `sbrk`, and that's fine.

When I proceed with a pop I can retrive my value, but I can't free the allocated space. Is there any way to do this?

The `sbrk` syscall doesn't accept negative numbers. I've already tried.

Comment: I guess you're using MARS or SPIM toy system calls, not [Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) or some other real OS with a fully functional `sbrk` library function or system call.  I updated tags accordingly.

Comment: you're right, sorry but i'm a bit unexperienced in this field

Comment: No problem, just make sure to specify the details of whatever system you're using in future questions; it's often relevant, and at least gives context for answerers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MIPS - free dynamically allocated space (heap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850718/mips-free-dynamically-allocated-space-heap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the real `sbrk` in UNIX, QtSpim/MARS syscall #9 doesn't support returning memory from the heap back to the system.

But, you can implement `sbrk` functionality yourself, as it is fairly simple.  (`malloc`/`free` would be more complex involving free lists and such, but this is much simpler.)

You need a subroutine that takes the adjustment number just like the real `sbrk`, of course, and maintains a small amount of persistent/global state — maybe two words: the UNIX-style `sbrk` address and the MARS-style syscall #9 address, or, one of those or the other and a free count.

Releasing memory (negative `sbrk` parameter) simply means moving the UNIX-style `sbrk` address back and/or increasing the free count, and otherwise doing nothing.

Later allocations (positive `sbrk` parameter) consider the gap between markers, or free count, in allocating new heap space, and only increase underlying MARS heap if free count goes to 0 and there's still more bytes in the allocation request.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i proceeded with this solution and i'm monitoring the heap manually with two words

Answer (score -1):

In MIPS, heap memory can be freed by using the sbrk system call and adjusting the program break address accordingly.

Comment: Are you talking about Linux?  This question seems to be about the SPIM and MARS simulators, which have their own set of toy system calls.  As documented by https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html - `sbrk`'s arg is the number of bytes to allocate, not a new break address.  Are you saying the number of bytes to allocate can be negative, or are you talking about a different environment?